# Pandas dataframe manipulation/re-sizing of a single-column count file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a file that looks like this:

```
gRNA_A
gene_a
140626
gene_b
227598
gene_c
115781
gRNA_B
gene_a
125003
gene_b
102000
gene_c
200300
```

I want to read this into a pandas dataframe and re-shape it so that it looks like this:

```
        gene_a gene_b gene_c
gRNA_A  140626 227598 115781
gRNA_B  125003 102000 200300
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Notes: it will not always be this size, so the solution needs to be size-independent. The input file will be max ~200gRNAs x 20genes. There will be gRNA_somelettercombos, but the gene will not be named gene_lettercombo-- the gene will be the name of an actual gene (like GAPDH, ACTB, etc.).

Comment: Yes, everything is possible, but you need to give more details on how to identify the different parts. Using the literal `gRNA` string? Using the known number of elements? Is the number of elements per group constant? etc.

Comment: Yes, there will be gRNA_somelettercombos, but the gene will not be named gene_lettercombo-- the gene will be the name of an actual gene (like GAPDH, ACTB, etc).

Comment: are there really double spaces between the lines? Can we rely on having / not having spaces? Do you expect to have very large files?  Please try to give the most meaningful details

Comment: sorry, this is my first post. The original file does not have double spaces (the formatting was hard for me). The original file, on every new line, has either gRNA_letter, gene, or a count. The files will be at most 200 gRNAs and 20 genes, so not super big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a parser for your custom format, relying on the `gRNA` string to start a new group and then taking odd elements as key and even as value:

```
d = {}
current_rRNA = None
gene = None

with open('gRNA.txt') as f:
    for line in f:                    # iterate over lines
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:                  # skip blank lines
            continue
        if line.startswith('gRNA_'):  # start new group
            current_rRNA = line
            d[current_rRNA] = {}
        else:
            if gene:                  # even line of a group = data
                d[current_rRNA][gene] = int(line)
                gene = None
            else:                     # odd line of a group = gene name
                gene = line

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

output:

```
        gene_a  gene_b  gene_c
gRNA_A  140626  227598  115781
gRNA_B  125003  102000  200300
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way, but this works for the given example.

I created a file `data.txt` with provided sample.

I assumed the count is always a number.

```
def file_parser(f_path):
    data_dict = {}
    my_gRNA = None
    my_gene = None
    with open(f_path, "r") as f:
        for each in f:
            if not each:
                continue
            each = each.strip()
            if each.startswith("gRNA"):
                if each not in data_dict:
                    data_dict[each] = {}
                my_gRNA = each
            elif not each.isnumeric() and isinstance(each, str) and not each.startswith("gRNA"):
                my_gene = each
            elif each.isnumeric():
                data_dict[my_gRNA][my_gene] = each
        return data_dict
    

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_parser("data.txt"), orient='index')
```

```
df.head()
        gene_a  gene_b  gene_c
gRNA_A  140626  227598  115781
gRNA_B  125003  102000  200300
```

*Note: This answer is very similar to the one by *mozway*. The only difference is in the parser, where I explicitly check for numeric types.*

Comment: This is quite similar to my solution ;) I'd recommend not to read the whole file and then loop but rather to process while reading the file. This enables to handle large files

Comment: Agreed, its very similar to yours. And, yes, your way of reading the file is much more memory efficient. I just did not assume that my odd lines are gene name. I did an explicit check.

Comment: at least the other answer has some explanation you don't even have that. and your `if not each: continue` isn't hit except possibly for the very last line.